# I have taken screen shot of a form made in netbeans. 1130X800 size

Tags: java, netbeans, screenshot

I have written code to take screenshot of a netbeans jPanel. But when it is saved the resolution is reduced and the print is not readable (on printer sheet). As you can see the code.

```
  public static void getScreenShot(String filename) throws AWTException, IOException
{
    int width = BILL.getWidth()*4;
    int height = BILL.getHeight()*4;
BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(BILL.getWidth(),BILL.getHeight(),BufferedImage.SCALE_REPLICATE);
BILL.setSize(width,height);
BILL.doLayout();
Graphics2D g2d = img.createGraphics();
g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ALPHA_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_ALPHA_INTERPOLATION_QUALITY);
g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_COLOR_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_COLOR_RENDER_QUALITY);
g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_DITHERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_DITHER_ENABLE);
g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_FRACTIONALMETRICS, RenderingHints.VALUE_FRACTIONALMETRICS_ON);
g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_STROKE_CONTROL, RenderingHints.VALUE_STROKE_PURE);
BILL.printAll(g2d);

BILL.printAll(img.getGraphics());
//printImage(img);
ImageIO.write(img, "png", new File (filename));
g2d.dispose();
}
```

[image]

How can I fix the screenshot and printing quality.

Comment: The image you added to the post was `970x710`. When printing, you should use ~300ppi for best quality. This means that unless you want your picture to be 3 inches wide, you need to use a higher resolution monitor. You can't screenshot at a resolution that's higher than what your computer is displaying.

Comment: Is there another way to save the jpanel as a custom bill. I mean in a different file or format or something.